# Template definition with template template parameter for class that can specialize, for instance, to std::vector<std::string> or std::map<std::tree>

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I want to create a template class that can hold any combination of container and containee. For example, a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::map<std::tree>`, for instance.

I have tried a lot of combinations, but I must admit that the complexity of templates overwhelms me. The closes I have made compile is something like this:

```
template <class Vector, template <typename, class Containee = std::string> class Container>
class GenericContainer
{
    Container<Containee> mLemario;
};
```

Although it compiles so far, then, when I want to instantiate it I rreceive lots of errors.

```
MyContainer<std::vector, std::string> myContainer;
```

Am I using the correct approach to create that kind of class?

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::map<std::tree>`, because (1) there is no `std::tree` and (2) `std::map` requires (at least) two parameters: `key` and `value`: `std::map<key,value>`. So what do you think the containee of a `std::map` is? Its `key`, or its `value`, or `std::pair<key,value>` (this is actually what `std::map::value_type` gives you)?

Comment: what functionality it would support? how are you going to use it? asking because different containers provide very different functionality with different complexity. They cannot be interchanged. In general I think it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `std::vector` (and the like) @[songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao) provided an excellent answer. But since you also mentioned `std::map`, I'll add a simple extension of @[songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao)'s answer, [online](http://cpp.sh/56tvf).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee = std::string, typename... extras>
class GenericContainer
{
    Container<Containee, extras ...> mLemario;
    // Use 'Containee' here (if needed) like sizeof(Containee) 
    // or have another member variable like: Containee& my_ref.
};

int main()
{
    GenericContainer<std::vector, std::string> myContainer1;
    GenericContainer<std::vector, std::string, std::allocator<std::string>> myContainer2; // Explicitly using std::allocator<std::string>
    GenericContainer<std::map, std::string, int> myContainer3; // Map: Key = std::string, Value = int
}
```

Comment: Great! As I supposed, this is not for beginners. It compiles so far.

Comment: I find it extremely difficult to instantiate a function outside of the template declaration: I'm trying something like this: template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee = std::string, typename... extras>
Containee GenericContainer<>::transform_word(const Containee& word) {} but it doesn't matter what i put inside GenericContainer<...>, it won't compile @songyuanyao

Comment: Have a look here: http://cpp.sh/94kih. Let me know if that does not help. If it gets very complicated, then perhaps ask a new question.

Comment: it works. I'll create another question for my last wish: function specialization

Comment: -1 This is bad advice/design: `Containee` is not needed as `template` parameters, since it is readily known as `Container::value_type`. Similar, `extras` is not needed either, since it is implicit in `Container` (and not used anywhere in your class).

Comment: For `Container=std::map` you are forced to have `Containee=Key`. This makes no sense.

Comment: @Walter Yes, for `Container=std::map` the name is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to create a template class that can hold any combination of container and containee

You should use [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for template template parameter `Container`, and `Containee`, then they could be used with arbitrary number/type of template parameters. e.g.

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename... Containee>
class GenericContainer
{
    Container<Containee...> mLemario;
};
```

then

```
GenericContainer<std::vector, std::string> myContainer1;
GenericContainer<std::map, std::string, int> myContainer2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard containers declare names for their element types, so you can write

```
template<typename Container>
class GenericContainer
{
    using Containee = typename Container::value_type;
};
```

You get to use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    GenericContainer<std::vector<std::string>> myContainer;
}
```

You can use non-default allocators with such containers, but don't get to easily create similar containers with different element types.  That may or may not be an obstacle for you.

Comment: I think you mean `Container::value_type`

Comment: Not exactly what I want, as I want std::string to by also a parameter

Comment: @HolaMundo First, you didn't specify this. Second, you can easily create a template alias declaration that deals with that.

Comment: Thanks @Walter for the edit - I should take more care!

Comment: @Walter Yes, I did, in the first line of my question: _I want to create a template class that can hold any combination of container and containee. For example, a std::vector<std::string> or std::map<std::tree>._

Comment: @HolaMundo Yes, but a type like `std::vector<std::string>` is already a *container and containee*.