# Function specialization in template definition with template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Following the advise of @Jonas in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811378/template-definition-with-template-template-parameter-for-class-that-can-speciali), I am defining a templatized class to hold an arbitrary container (vector, set, map, etc) of an arbitrary containee (string, tree, etc). So far, my definition is like this:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee = std::string, typename... extras>
class Lemario
{
public:
    typedef typename Container<Containee, extras...>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename Container<Containee, extras...>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    // Use 'Containee' here (if needed) like sizeof(Containee)
    // or have another member variable like: Containee& my_ref.
    Container<Containee, extras ...> mTheContainer;
    int loadContainees(const char *filename) {
        Containee w, line;
        // do some stuff here
    }
    void appendContainee(const Containee &__x);
};
```

Now, I can define methods both inline (like loadContainees) an outside of the template definition. Outside:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee, typename... extras>
Containee Lemario<Container, Containee, extras...>::transform_word(const     Containee& word) const
{
    Containee result;
    return result;
}
```

So far so good.

But now I want to specialize a method to append a Contaniee to the Container as vector, map, tree, use different methods. So I try to specialize std::vector:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee, typename... extras>
void Lemario<std::vector, Word>::appendContainee(const Word & word)
{
     mTheContainer.push_back(word);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: prototype for ‘void Lemario<std::vector, gong::Xtring>::appendContainee(const Word&)’ does not match any in class ‘Lemario<std::vector, gong::Xtring>’
```

Apart from that, ¿can I only specialize the Container, std::vector, but let the Containee unspecialized?

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee, typename... extras>
void Lemario<std::vector, Containee>::appendContainee(const Containee & word)
{
    mTheContainer.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cant specialize function from class template separately from class itself

Comment: This is a typical XY problem. The correct answer to your previous question was that by Toby Speight. You don't need this complicated structure here.

Comment: **ERROR** `Word` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I have created a script on cpp.sh: http://cpp.sh/4pn4z

Comment: FYI the variable name `__x` is a [reserved identifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation of `appendContainee` has syntax errors. The proper way to specialize the function for `std::vector` and `Word` is to write it like so:

```
template <>
void Lemario<std::vector, Word>::appendContainee(const Word & word)
{
     mTheContainer.push_back(word);
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PCTSULk4zi0xZWLH)

---

This approach, however, requires that you FULLY specialize the function each time, meaning you have to specify both the container *and* the type. Likely you only want to specialize for `std::vector` and not also for `Word`.

This problem is classically solved with a **tagged-dispatch** pattern. In tagged dispatch, we turn specialization into an overloading problem by introducing helper methods that will be selected properly via overloading.

We create an empty nested templated struct within our class:

```
private:
   template<class...>
   struct Lemario_tag{};
```

And then write `private` helper methods that the entry point method will call:

```
template<class T>
void appendContaineeHelp(const Containee &x, Lemario_tag<T>)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "No specialization exists for this container");
}

void appendContaineeHelp(const Containee &x, Lemario_tag<std::vector<Containee, extras...>>)
{
    mTheContainer.push_back(x);
}
```

The first is a catch-all that will cause a compiler error if you try to call it with a non-specialized container.

The second is specialized for a `std::vector`.

We define our `public` `appendContainee` like so (simple pass-through):

```
void appendContainee(const Containee &x){
    appendContaineeHelp(x, Lemario_tag<Container<Containee, extras...>>{});
}
```

We can use our container like so:

```
Lemario<std::vector, std::string> vecString;
Lemario<std::vector, int> vecInt;
vecString.appendContainee("foo");
vecInt.appendContainee(1);

Lemario<std::set, int> set_int;
// set_int.appendContainee(1); // compiler error
```

### [Better Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SPoEOTRAMta9d2GW)

Comment: The first approach works fine for me. The second one is far beyond my knowledge and requeriments, but anyway, it opens my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize the function using `std::enable_if` (and SFINAE), here is an example, [online](http://cpp.sh/3yf4c).

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Containee = std::string, typename... extras>
class Lemario
{
public:
    typedef typename Container<Containee, extras...>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename Container<Containee, extras...>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    // Use 'Containee' here (if needed) like sizeof(Containee)
    // or have another member variable like: Containee& my_ref.
    Container<Containee, extras ...> mTheContainer;
    int loadContainees(const char *filename) {
        Containee w, line;
        // do some stuff here
        return 0; // To make the compiler happy
    }

    template <typename Containee2> // For SFINAE to work
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Container<Containee2, extras...>, std::vector<Containee2, extras...>>::value>::type
    appendContainee(const Containee2 & word)
    {
         mTheContainer.push_back(word);
    }

    template <typename Containee2> // For SFINAE to work
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Container<Containee2, extras...>, std::deque<Containee2, extras...>>::value>::type
    appendContainee(const Containee2 & word)
    {
         mTheContainer.push_back(word);
    }
};
```

**Example**

```
int main()
{
  Lemario<std::vector, int> foo;
  std::cout << foo.mTheContainer.size() << std::endl;
  foo.appendContainee(1);
  std::cout << foo.mTheContainer.size() << std::endl;

  Lemario<std::deque, int> bar;
  std::cout << bar.mTheContainer.size() << std::endl;
  bar.appendContainee(1);
  std::cout << bar.mTheContainer.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this approach also works, but the one from @AndyG is what I was looking for.

Comment: @HolaMundo Ok, but I don't see how that (his first solution) accomplishes: *can I only specialize the Container, `std::vector`, but let the Containee unspecialized?* Which is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: you are right, that was a requeriment that I added like a bonus just out of curiosity, but actualy I didn't need it.

Comment: @HolaMundo Well, that part seemed the most fun to solve :-)